# C++ 'unresolved errors' using Intel's oneAPI compiler, possibly involved with the Math Kernel Library?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, compiler-errors, fftw, intel-oneapi

I'm trying to run the following code on an Ubuntu machine:

```
/**
 For compiling --> 
        export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY='0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80,84,88,92,96,100,104,108,112,116,120,124,128,132,136,140,144,148,152,156,160,164,168,172,176,180,184,188,192,196,200,204,208,212,216,220,224,228,232,236,240,244,248,252,256,260,264,268'
        export OMP_NUM_THREADS=68
        set MKL_NUM_THREADS = 68
        icc -std=gnu++98 -O3 -qopenmp -xhost -ansi-alias -ipo -AVX512 mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P.cpp -o mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P -lm -mkl
 For running -->
 *      ./mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P N T numThreads
 *      Example: ./mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P 1000 100000 1      
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <complex.h>
#include "mkl_service.h"
#include "mkl_dfti.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdio>

 #include <omp.h>

// #include <cilk/cilk.h>
// #include <cilk/cilk_api.h>    
// #include "cilktime.h"
#ifdef USE_PAPI
#include <papi.h>    
#include "papilib.h"
#endif

#ifdef POLYBENCH
    #include <polybench.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

typedef vector<double>            vd;
typedef vector<vector<double> >   vvd;

#define PB          push_back
#define SZ(x)       (int)x.size()
#define MAXN        8010

int T, N, N_THREADS;
const int BASE = 1024;
double a1[MAXN][MAXN], a2[MAXN][MAXN];
// double *forward_input_buffer, *backward_output_buffer;
// double complex *forward_output_buffer, *backward_input_buffer;

double complex *a_complex, *odd_mults, *input_complex;

double *mkl_forward_input_buffer, *mkl_backward_output_buffer;
double complex *mkl_forward_output_buffer, *mkl_backward_input_buffer;

template<class T> void out(const vector<T> &a) { cout<<"array: "; for (int i=0;i<SZ(a);i++) cout<<a[i]<<" "; cout<<endl; cout.flush(); }

long getTime(){
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;

    return ms;
}

void pad_matrix(vvd &v, int rows, int cols){
    int pad_rows = rows - SZ(v);
    int pad_cols = cols - SZ(v[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < pad_rows; i++)
        v.PB(vd(SZ(v[0]), 0.0));

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ(v); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pad_cols; j++)
            v[i].PB(0.0);
    }
}

// Resizing matrices to [r1+r2, c1+c2] for circular convolution
void  pad_vectors(vd &input, vd &formula)
{
    int n = SZ(input);
    vd tmp = vd(n*3, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tmp[i] = tmp[n + i] = tmp[n + n + i] = input[i];
    input = tmp;

    int diff = abs(SZ(input) - SZ(formula));
    for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
        if (SZ(input) < SZ(formula))
            input.PB(0.0);
        else
            formula.PB(0.0);
}

void print_matrix(vvd v, string msg){
    cout << msg << ": " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ(v); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ(v[i]); j++)
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_matrix_arr(double *v, int n, string msg){
    cout << msg << ": " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << v[i*n + j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_complex_matrix(double complex* input_buffer1, double complex* input_buffer2, int n, string msg){
    cout << msg << ": " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++){
        if (i % n == 0)
            cout << endl;
        printf("ratio:%f\t%f%+fi\t \t%f%+fi\n", crealf(input_buffer1[i])/crealf(input_buffer2[i]), crealf(input_buffer1[i]), cimagf(input_buffer1[i]), crealf(input_buffer2[i]), cimagf(input_buffer2[i]));
        // cout << (*input_buffer[i]).real() << " " << (*input_buffer[i]).imag() << ",\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_vector(vd v, string msg){
    cout << msg << ": ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ(v); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}


// fftw_plan plan_forward, plan_backward;
DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE my_desc1_handle = NULL, my_desc2_handle = NULL;
// double mkl_forward_input_buffer[MAXN * MAXN], mkl_backward_output_buffer[MAXN * MAXN];
// double complex mkl_forward_output_buffer[MAXN * MAXN], mkl_backward_input_buffer[MAXN * MAXN];


// DFT of real valued matrix. CAUTION: initialize the input array after creating the plan
void mkl_fft_forward(vvd &v,  double complex *output_buffer, int n)
{
    int sz_i = SZ(v), sz_j = SZ(v[0]);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < sz_i; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < sz_j; j++){
            mkl_forward_input_buffer[i*n + j] = v[i][j];
        }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            mkl_forward_output_buffer[i*n + j] = 0.0;

    // print_matrix_arr(mkl_forward_input_buffer, n, "input bufer");

    DftiComputeForward(my_desc1_handle, mkl_forward_input_buffer, mkl_forward_output_buffer);


    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            output_buffer[i*n + j] = mkl_forward_output_buffer[i*n + j];
            // printf("%f+%f\n", crealf(output_buffer[i*n + j]), cimagf(output_buffer[i*n+j]));
        }
    }
}

// Inverse DFT of complex input array
void mkl_fft_backward(double complex* input_buffer, vvd &output, int n)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            mkl_backward_input_buffer[i*n + j] = input_buffer[i*n + j];
            mkl_backward_output_buffer[i*n + j] = 0.0;
        }

    DftiComputeBackward(my_desc2_handle, mkl_backward_input_buffer, mkl_backward_output_buffer);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            output[i][j] = mkl_backward_output_buffer[i*n + j]/(n * n * 1.0);
}

// Takes two array(a_real and b_real) as input and writes the output to "res"
void convolution_fftw_2d(vvd &a_real, vvd &input, vvd &result)
{
    if (T == 0)
        return ;

    int n_formula = N;
    mkl_fft_forward(a_real, a_complex, n_formula);
    // double complex* odd_mults = fftw_alloc_complex(n_formula * n_formula); // Do not need to allocate new space, we can use the space of a_complex or b_complex
    bool is_initialized = false; // if odd_mult array is initialized

    int t = T;
    // ############# Repeated squaring - start ############
    while (t > 1){
        if (t & 1){
            if (is_initialized == false){
                #pragma omp parallel for
                for(int i = 0; i < n_formula * n_formula; i++)
                    odd_mults[i] = a_complex[i];
                is_initialized = true;
            } else {
                #pragma omp parallel for
                for(int i = 0; i < n_formula * n_formula; i++)
                    odd_mults[i] = odd_mults[i] * a_complex[i];
            }
        }
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < n_formula * n_formula; i++)
            a_complex[i] = a_complex[i] * a_complex[i];         
        t /= 2;
    }
    if (is_initialized){
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < n_formula * n_formula; i++)
            a_complex[i] = a_complex[i] * odd_mults[i];
    }
    // ############# Repeated squaring - end ############

    // while (--t > 0){
    //     cout << "t: " << t << endl;
    //     for(int i = 0; i < n_formula * n_formula; i++)
    //         pointwise_mult[i] = pointwise_mult[i] * a_complex[i];  
    // }
 
    // fft_backward(a_complex, formula, n_formula);

    // // Scale the output array according to number of samples
    // #pragma omp parallel for
    // for (int i = 0; i < SZ(formula); i++)
    //     for (int j = 0; j < SZ(formula[0]); j++){
    //         double r = formula[i][j] / (n_formula * n_formula);
    //         formula[i][j] = r;
    //         // formula[i][j] = (abs(r) < 1e-8? 0:r);
    //     }
    // print_matrix(formula, "Formula");

    // vvd input(N, vd(N, 0.0));
    // #pragma omp parallel for
    // for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    //     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
    //         input[i][j] = a1[i][j];
    // }
    // print_matrix(input, "Input");

    // reverse(input.begin(), input.end());

    // double complex* formula_complex = fftw_alloc_complex(N * N); 
    // fft_forward(formula, formula_complex, N);

    // double complex* input_complex = fftw_alloc_complex(N * N); 
    
    mkl_fft_forward(input, input_complex, N);
    // fft_forward(input, input_complex, N);


    // double complex* result_complex = fftw_alloc_complex(n * n); // Do not need to allocate new space, we can use the space of a_complex or b_complex
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++){
        a_complex[i] = input_complex[i] * a_complex[i];
    }

    mkl_fft_backward(a_complex, result, N);
    // fft_backward(a_complex, result, N);
    // print_matrix(result, "Result (needs to be rotated)");

    return ;
}

void mkl_init(int n)
{
    MKL_LONG status;
    MKL_LONG len[2] = {n, n};
    len[0] = n; len[1] = n;

    status = DftiCreateDescriptor(&my_desc1_handle, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 2, len);
    status = DftiSetValue(my_desc1_handle, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_NOT_INPLACE);
    status = DftiSetValue(my_desc1_handle, DFTI_CONJUGATE_EVEN_STORAGE, DFTI_COMPLEX_COMPLEX);
    status = DftiSetValue( my_desc1_handle, DFTI_PACKED_FORMAT, DFTI_CCE_FORMAT );  
    status = DftiCommitDescriptor(my_desc1_handle);

    status = DftiCreateDescriptor(&my_desc2_handle, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 2, len);
    status = DftiSetValue(my_desc2_handle, DFTI_CONJUGATE_EVEN_STORAGE, DFTI_COMPLEX_COMPLEX);
    status = DftiSetValue(my_desc2_handle, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_NOT_INPLACE);
    status = DftiSetValue( my_desc2_handle, DFTI_PACKED_FORMAT, DFTI_CCE_FORMAT );  
    status = DftiCommitDescriptor(my_desc2_handle);
}

void initialize(){
    mkl_init(N);

    // forward_input_buffer = fftw_alloc_real(N * N);
    // backward_output_buffer = fftw_alloc_real(N * N);
    // forward_output_buffer = fftw_alloc_complex(N * N);
    // backward_input_buffer = fftw_alloc_complex(N * N);

    a_complex = (double complex *)malloc(sizeof(double complex) * N * N); //fftw_alloc_complex(N);
    odd_mults = (double complex *)malloc(sizeof(double complex) * N * N); //fftw_alloc_complex(N);
    input_complex = (double complex *)malloc(sizeof(double complex) * N * N); //fftw_alloc_complex(N);

    mkl_forward_input_buffer = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
    mkl_backward_output_buffer = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);

    mkl_forward_output_buffer = (double complex *)malloc(sizeof(double complex) * N * N);
    mkl_backward_input_buffer = (double complex *)malloc(sizeof(double complex) * N * N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N+2; ++i) 
        for (int j = 0; j < N+2; j++)
            a1[i][j] = a2[i][j] = 1.0 * (rand() % BASE); 
}

void mkl_destroy(){
    MKL_LONG status;
    status = DftiFreeDescriptor(&my_desc1_handle);
    status = DftiFreeDescriptor(&my_desc2_handle);

    free(a_complex);
    free(odd_mults);
    free(input_complex);

    free(mkl_forward_input_buffer);
    free(mkl_backward_output_buffer);
    free(mkl_forward_output_buffer);
    free(mkl_backward_input_buffer);
}


#define getIdx(i, N)   ((i + N) % N)


bool verify(vvd result){


    for (int t = 0; t < T; ++t) {
        // cout << "t: " << t << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                // a2[i] = 0.125 * (a1[i+1] - 2.0 * a1[i] + a1[i-1]); 
                // cout << i << " " << j << " : " << getIdx(i -1, N) << " " << getIdx(i + 1, N) << " " << getIdx(j - 1, N) << " " << getIdx(j + 1, N) << endl;
                // a2[i][j] = a1[getIdx(i - 1, N)][getIdx(j, N)] + a1[getIdx(i, N)][getIdx(j + 1, N)] 
                //             + a1[getIdx(i + 1, N)][getIdx(j, N)] + a1[getIdx(i, N)][getIdx(j - 1, N)];

                a2[i][j] = 0.125*a1[getIdx(i - 1, N)][getIdx(j, N)] + 0.125*a1[getIdx(i, N)][getIdx(j + 1, N)] 
                            + 0.125*a1[getIdx(i + 1, N)][getIdx(j, N)] + 0.125*a1[getIdx(i, N)][getIdx(j - 1, N)] 
                            + (-2.0*(0.125*2.0) + 1.0)*a1[i][j];
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                a1[i][j] = a2[i][j];
    }

    // cout << "Final Answer (iter): ";
    // for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    //     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    //         cout << a1[i][j] << " ";
    //     cout << endl;
    // }
    // cout << endl;


    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (fabs (a1[i][j] - result[i][j]) > 1e-8)
                cnt++;

    cout << "Number of Mismatched Cell: " << cnt << endl;


    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double x;
    int t, n, numThreads;
    // vvd a, b;

    if (argc < 4){
        cout << "Enter: N T numThreads" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 1){
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    if (argc > 2)
        t = atoi(argv[2]);

    numThreads = 1;
    if (argc > 3){
        numThreads = atoi(argv[3]);
        omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);
    }

    N = n; T = t; N_THREADS = numThreads;

    initialize();
    #ifdef USE_PAPI
        papi_init();
    #endif

    int sz_formula = 3;
    // double formula[3][3] = {{0, 1, 0},
    //                         {1, 0, 1},
    //                         {0, 1, 0}}; 

    double formula[3][3] = {{0, 0.125, 0},
                            {0.125, (-2.0*(0.125*2.0) + 1.0), 0.125},
                            {0, 0.125, 0}}; 
    // double formula[3][3] = {{1, 0, 1},
    //                         {0, 0, 0},
    //                         {0, 0, 0}}; 
    vvd a(sz_formula, vd(sz_formula));
    for (int i = 0; i < sz_formula; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sz_formula; j++)
            a[i][j] = formula[i][j];
    
    vvd input(n, vd(n)), result(n, vd(n,0.0));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            input[i][j] = a1[i][j];

    long start = getTime();
#ifdef POLYBENCH
    /* Start timer. */
    polybench_start_instruments;
#endif

    convolution_fftw_2d(a, input, result);
    // Result must be rotated (T mod N) indices
    
#ifdef POLYBENCH
    /* Stop and print timer. */
    polybench_stop_instruments;
    polybench_print_instruments;
#endif
    long end = getTime();

    vvd rotated_result(n, vd(n, 0.0));
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            rotated_result[i][j] = result[(i+(t%n)) % n][(j+(t%n)) % n];
    // print_matrix(rotated_result, "rotated");

    cout << N << "," << T << "," << numThreads << "," << (end - start) / 1000.0 << endl;

    mkl_destroy();
    
#ifdef USE_PAPI        
    countTotalMiss(p);
    PAPI_shutdown();
    delete threadcounter;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) delete l2miss[i];
    delete l2miss;
    delete errstring;
    delete EventSet;
    delete eventCode;
#endif

    long start_iter = getTime();
    // verify(rotated_result);
    long end_iter = getTime();

    // cout << "Time (Iter): " << end_iter - start_iter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to running C++ overall (I'm most familiar with Python, which is an interpreted language), so I'm not sure how it all works. This was pre-made code that I have to test before I make my own. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and to begin with, I'm not sure how to work everything. I have Visual Studio Code installed, and I'm trying to run the command `icc -std=gnu++98 -O3 -qopenmp -xhost -ansi-alias -ipo -AVX512 mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P.cpp -o mkl_2d_heat_fftw_P -lm -mkl` through the terminal. I'm not even sure if this is right, but I'm getting the following error messages:

`ipo: warning #11021 (6 times): unresolved DftiFreeDescriptor, DftiCommitDescriptor, DftiSetValue, DftiCreateDescriptor_d_md, DftiComputeBackward, DftiComputeForward`

`ld: cannot find (3 times): -lmkl_intel_lp64, -lmkl_intel_thread, -lmkl_core.`

These are eventually meant to run on supercomputers at my institution, but is the compiling command wrong for my local computer? If it helps, I'm running this on a VirtualBox on Windows 10 Pro (I tried running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Hyper-V but I never figured out how to successfully connect it to the Internet because whenever I made the VM's switch my WiFi one, it made my computer overall have no Internet access).

Looking at it, it seems like the Math Kernel Library is the problem, though I'm not too sure. Did I mess up the installation of the oneAPI Base Toolkit? I have every oneAPI Toolkit installed (and all of their features too, including FPGA support).

Or am I just compiling it wrong as the script described listed in the top comment is for a supercomputer (I'm not sure what to do with the first three lines, like `export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`, `export OMP_NUM_THREADS`, and `set MKL_NUM_THREADS`).

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What happens when you remove `-ipo` from the command line options? IPO stands for "interprocedural optimization", most likely is performed by the linker, and is optional. Now, the real errors are with  `-lmkl_intel_lp64` etc. These are definitively link-time errors.  Are you sure there's a file `liblmkl_intel_lp64.*` where `*` may stand for the extension `a`, `so`, `so.1`, `so.2.3` etc? Try to run `find /usr -name "liblmkl_intel_lp64.*"` and tell me the output from this command. This kind of problems is very typical and usually easy to fix.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).